# Laravel, How to automatic create thumb folder with Image/Intervation resize method

Tags: laravel

I need when upload article image, automatic upload Original Image Size and resize image in `thumb` folder.

but in this method i receive this error (`thumb` folder can not automatic create) :

```
Can't write image data to path (storage/upload/images/articles/1400/05/06/thumb/Bx1WRTtp9IgSZgnP8VE11627500167.jpg)
```

Upload Image Method :

```
protected function articleUploadImage($file, $folder, $size)
{
    $d = jdate();
    $year = $d->format('Y');
    $month = $d->format('m');
    $day = $d->format('d');

    $direct = 'storage/upload/images/'. $folder . '/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $day;
    $directWithResize = 'storage/upload/images/'. $folder . '/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $day . '/thumb';
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = Str::random(20) . time() . '.' . $extension;


    // if (!is_dir($directWithResize)) {
    //     mkdir($directWithResize);       
    // }

    //$path = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
    //$path->resize(100, 100);
    //$path->save(public_path($directWithResize  . '/' . $fileName));
    

    Image::make($file->getRealPath())->fit($size, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save($direct . '/thumb/' . $fileName);


    //$path = $file->store($direct);
    //$newPath = $direct;
    
    return $direct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading an image, you should create a directory.

```php
protected function articleUploadImage($file, $folder, $size)
{
    $d = jdate();
    $year = $d->format('Y');
    $month = $d->format('m');
    $day = $d->format('d');

    $direct = 'storage/upload/images/'. $folder . '/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $day;
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = Str::random(20) . time() . '.' . $extension;
 

    if (!file_exists($direct . '/thumb/')) {
            mkdir($direct . '/thumb/', 666, true);
    }

    Image::make($file->getRealPath())->fit($size, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->save($direct . '/thumb/' . $fileName);
 
    
    return $direct;
}
```

Comment: but when i Upload Image, automatic create folders. when use `mkdir`, i receive `mkdir(): Permission denied` error in Macbook Pro.